# Problem with dplyr to change column names

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm receiving an error message "Error: `data` must be uniquely named but has duplicate elements" when using he dplyr package to change column names. It works fine up to line 116 of my code. Then starting at line 117 I get the above error. I do not think I've done anything different with the code, so I'm not sure why I'd get this error. All of my google searches for the error result in instructions for how to deduplicate a dataframe. I am at a loss for what is happening.

I've tried opening/closing R several times, reviewed/confirmed I am not using duplicate column names, and googled for any similar issues with no luck.

Works fine:

```
#Section 3: Reasons for staying here
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(KEEPHERE_family = q31_1)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(KEEPHERE_work = q31_2)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(KEEPHERE_nature = q31_3)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(KEEPHERE_sensecomm = q31_4)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(KEEPHERE_health = q31_5)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(KEEPHERE_safe = q31_6)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(KEEPHERE_school = q31_7)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(KEEPHERE_retire = q31_8)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(KEEPHERE_adventure = q31_9)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(KEEPHERE_famous = q31_10)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(KEEPHERE_history = q31_11)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(KEEPHERE_prohcost = q31_12)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(KEEPHERE_other = q31_13)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(KEEPHERE_othertext = q31_13_text)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(fun2 = q32)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(fun2othtext = q32_text)
```

Fails and gives error "Error: `data` must be uniquely named but has duplicate elements"

```
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(TOPRSNMOVED_othtxt = q43a_text)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(RSNSLEAVE_products = q42b_1)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(RSNSLEAVE_costhous = q42b_2)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(RSNSLEAVE_costliv = q42b_3)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(RSNSLEAVE_limtjobopp = q42b_4)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(RSNSLEAVE_joboffisld = q42b_5)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(RSNSLEAVE_betterschl = q42b_6)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(RSNSLEAVE_traffic = q42b_7)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(RSNSLEAVE_closfamly = q42b_8)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(RSNSLEAVE_toosmall = q42b_9)
ILS <- ILS %>% rename(RSNSLEAVE_immigration = q42b_10)
```

I expect to change the column names to meaningful variable names.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create a string of names and the matching column names and use it in `set_names` or `setnames` (from `data.table`) in one step.  If you want to use with dplyr, there is `rename_at`.  The error suggest that you may have accidentally named with one value which is also existing

Comment: Using `dplyr::rename_at` or `rename_all` So you would rename everything at the same time (like what akrun suggested with `data.table`) and you won't end up with unwanted duplicates and it's easier to keep track of that.

Comment: Also, instead of saving the data at each step, you can pass multiple statements in `rename`: `ILS <- ILS %>% rename(TOPRSNMOVED_othtxt = q43a_text, RSNSLEAVE_products = q42b_1, ...)`